# form submit confirmation to handle bootstrap button

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I added a delete confirmation to a form like so..

```
  $('#deleteform').submit(function(){
    return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this subscriber?');
  });
```

problem is while using twitter bootstrap, when the submit button is clicked the button is disabled and the buttons loading text is displayed because of this..

```
  $('.btn').live("click", function(){
    $(this).button('loading');
  });
```

to reset the button i use

```
button('reset')
```

So, If you press cancel at the delete confirmation the button is left in the 'loading' state.

Comment: Twitter does not disable submit buttons unless you are including the bootstrap JS. Can you provide some further details on what exactly you are doing.

Comment: Use of the `.live()` method is no longer recommended since later versions of jQuery offer better methods that do not have its drawbacks. See [here](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Comment: @ROYFinley is correct. `.live()` is depreciated. Use jQuery's `.on()` instead: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just selected all buttons apart from delete

```
  $('.update,.cancel,.enable,.disable').on("click", function(){
    $(this).button('loading');
  });
```

**Clarification..**

The submit button on the delete form and all other buttons on the page contained the class 'btn'

the code

```
  $('.btn').live("click", function(){
    $(this).button('loading');
  });
```

would put any button clicked into loading state (bootstrap feature)

This was what i wanted.. but my issue was the delete button was left in loading state if the delete confirmation was cancelled.

I had hoped to reset the button if confirmation was cancelled, but instead i have just excluded it from selection.

Comment: This answer needs more clarification so other users in the future can see your problem and clearly understand the solution.